# adb による apk 転送が遅い

Tags: android, adb

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314131/adb-transfers-file-with-a-very-slow-speed
こちらで質問されていますが、AndroidStudio(MacOSX Yosemite)の開発においてapkファイルの転送に時間がかかります。開発当初は気にならなかったのですが、ある時を境に転送に時間がかかるようになりました。
問題がどこにあるのか調べたところ、

```
adb push -p
```

を実行してベンチマークを取ったところ、転送率が60%のところで一旦止まり、その後は徐々に転送され結果的に転送速度は 120KB/s でした。

adbに問題がある可能性を考えplatform-toolsを再インストールしても結果は同じでした。

何か対処法はありますか？

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/sysctl.conf`を以下のように修正してMacを再起動してみてください

```
kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=1
net.inet.tcp.win_scale_factor=4
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.mssdflt=1448
net.inet.tcp.v6mssdflt=1412
net.inet.tcp.msl=15000
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=0
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=3
net.inet.tcp.slowstart_flightsize=20
net.inet.tcp.local_slowstart_flightsize=9
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
net.inet.icmp.icmplim=50
```

[参考リンク](https://rolande.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-os-x-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

USBケーブル等を変えても同じでしょうか？
USBのケーブルが充電専用のものとか、ケーブルの規格によってはダメな場合が有ります。
また、違う端末にプッシュした場合も同じですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。実は余計な画像を削除してアプリ自体を軽くしたので、この問題は起きなくなりました。

さきほど別の重いアプリで、ケーブルを変えて試したところ、やはり一旦止まります。だいたい8MBを過ぎたあたりです。
また、別の端末でも同様でした。
さらに他のケーブルでも試してみたいと思いますが、ケーブルを介さないエミュレーターへの転送も同様の遅さなので、悩ましいところです。